# Getting data back from database as undefined in html but defined in the console

Tags: javascript, crud

I am creating a slim project using CRUD. I am trying to get 1 user, by using GET. When I use .append it returns data like this: the name is the request getting data from the database.

- undefined
- name
- undefined
- name

Obviously I only want one user to be shown, however when I add .html instead of .append it just comes back undefined.

This is my code that is coming back undefined

```
 $(document).ready(function showStaff(processResponse) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "borrower.php/borrowers",
    success: showAllBorrowers,
    error: showError
}); 
});

//shows borrowers in HTML
function showAllBorrowers(responsedata){
$.each(responsedata.borrower,function(index,borrower){
    $("#borrower_list").append("<li type='square'> Borrower Id:"+borrower.borrower_id+",FullName:"+borrower.first_name+" "+borrower.last_name+", Email:"+borrower.email);
    $("#borrower_list").append("</li>");
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnSaveBorrower").click(function(){
    var borrower=new Borrower($("#firstName_add").val(),
                        $("#lastName_add").val(),$("#email_add").val());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url: "borrower.php/borrowers",
        data:JSON.stringify(borrower),
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data)
            location.reload();
        },
    });
   });
});


function Borrower(firstName, lastName, email){
this.firstname=firstName;
this.lastname=lastName;
this.email=email;
}


$("#btnSearch").click(function(){
    var id = $("#StaffBorrower_Id").val();
      $( "#update" ).show();
      $( ".delete" ).show();
      $("#btnUpdateBorrower").show();
      $("#btnDeleteBorrower").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                url: "borrower.php/borrowers/" + id,
                success: showResponse,
                error: showError
            });
 });

function showResponse(responsedata){
var item = $("<li>"); item.text("Borrower Id:"+responsedata.borrower_id+",FullName:" +responsedata.first_name+" "+responsedata.last_name+", Email:"+    responsedata.email);
    $("#search_borrower").html(item); 
    item.attr("type", "square"); 
    item.attr("data-delete-id", responsedata.borrower_id); item.attr("data-update-id", responsedata.borrower_id);
        console.dir(responsedata);
}


$("#btnDeleteBorrower").click(function(){
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if (result) {
        var staff= delete Borrower($("#borrower_Id").val(), $("#firstName").val(), $("#lastName").val(), $("#email").val()); 
            $.ajax({
                type: 'DELETE',
                dataType: "json",
                url: "borrower.php/borrowers/"+$("[data-delete-id]").data("delete-id"),
                success: function(res){
                    console.log(res);
                    location.reload();
                    },
                error: showError
            });
    }
});

$("#btnUpdateBorrower").click(function(){
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to update?");
        if (result) {
            var borrower = new Borrower ($("#firstName").val(),
                             $("#lastName").val(), 
                            $("#email").val());               
            $.ajax({
                type:'PUT',
                dataType:"json",
                url:"borrower.php/borrowers/"+$("[data-update-id]").data("update-id"),

                data:JSON.stringify(borrower),
                success:function(data){
                 console.log(data);
                 location.reload();
                },
                error: function(){
                 console.log("There seems to be an error")
                }
            }); 
        }
});
```

The console log is working, I am getting the data in the console but it isn't being returned in the html for some reason. Does anyone have any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: The object is getting populated *after* the code runs, but before you open your console. It's a console quirk - an object will only be computed/displayed *on demand* when the console is opened, not when it's logged.

Comment: The [`html` function takes a string or a function](http://api.jquery.com/html/), so passing a jQuery object is likely not going to work. [`append` takes lots of different types](http://api.jquery.com/append/). You'll probably want to use that. Note that you're appending, then setting attributes; you may want to set attributes, then append. It shouldn't matter, but it would make your code more readable. For this question, you'll want to provide what `responsedata` contains at the point it enters that function. Use `console.dir` instead of `log`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh right thanks, so how do I fix it? It is flicking from the name to undefined when I search for a name

Comment: Only call `showResponse` upon the resolution of the response - not before. Ideally, use a Promise.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I dont know what you mean. I will add all the code in the file to the question and could you tell me where to put it? please

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I used console.dir and that didnt change anything. I added all of my code, could you take a look at it and see what is wrong with it. It is exactly the same as another crud page, thats why I dont understand why it isnt working